# Why does the multiplicative homomorphism condition $F(xy)=F(x)F(y)$ not hold for $F: q ↦ kq$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In trying to prove that for k in $\mathbb{Q}$, $F: q ↦ kq$ is an automorphism, I came across the issue of $F(xy)=F(x)F(y)$ not holding as $F(xy)=kxy$ and $F(x)F(y)=k^2xy$. What am I wrongly assuming?

Edit: for $k \neq 0$

Edit: The question is as follows:

Prove that for each fixed nonzero $k ∈ \mathbb Q$ the map from $\mathbb Q$ to itself defined by $q↦kq$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb Q$

Comment: You have correctly come to the conclusion that for $k \neq 1$, the map you describe fails to be a homomorphism of rings. It is not clear why you find this problematic

Comment: If $k \not= 0$, then $F$ is an automorphism of the additive group ${\Bbb Q}$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann My confusion comes from knowing that F is an automorphism and having to prove it. My interpretation of this however was that F is not a homomorphism and as such cannot be an automorphism of $\mathbb Q$. Where is my thinking going wrong here?

Comment: @Deck How do you "know" that $F$ is an automorphism? Do you understand the difference between a ring automorphism and a group automorphism?

Comment: An automorphism of what?

Comment: @BenGrossmann it's a question from a book (Abstract Algebra 3rd Ed. by Dummit and Foote) and it has no mention of rings prior to this question. I'm just at a point of confusion where I'm not even sure which questions I should be asking

Comment: @Randall an automorphism of $\mathbb Q$

Comment: @Deck Note that $\Bbb Q$ is a group under addition, but not under multiplication. For multiplication to be a group operation, we would have to exclude $0 \in \Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Deck: $\mathbb{Q}$ has many algebraic structures. It is a group under addition; it is a (commutative) ring (with unity) under addition and multiplication. It is a monoid under multiplication. It is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. It is a module over a large number of rings. “Automorphism” doesn’t tell you, by itself, what structure you are looking at. The maps you have are automorphisms of the *additive group structure* of $\mathbb{Q}$, but not of *commutative ring structure* of $\mathbb{Q}$ (unless $k=1$). When we ask “of what’, it’s not the set we are asking about, but the algebraic structure.

Comment: @Deck In other words, the only requirement for $F$ to be an automorphism in this context is $F(x + y) = F(x) + F(y)$

Comment: @Deck  right, but as a what?  Set?  Group?  Vector space?  Field?

Comment: @BenGrossmann well it could also make sense as a vector space over itself, not just a group.